# How to close a url form R?

Tags: r, browser

I am attempting to open a url and close a url in an effort to fool my virtual machine into thinking I am working. I work in R with linx os. So I need it to open a browser wait a minute and close the browser.
my code so far:

```
repeat{
 startTime <- Sys.time()
 site <- browseURL("https://youtu.be/_W0bSen8Qjg")
 #does not work
 open(site)
 sleepTime <- startTime + 20 *60*60*60 -Sys.time()
 #does not work
 close(site) 
 if (sleepTime >0)
   Sys.sleep(sleepTime)
}
```

I can not figure out how to make the browser close.
Any thoughts or ideas would be helpful .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great project :)

I'd recommend working with `library(processx)` as it allows us to control the started process from within R. `See ?process`.

I tested this on windows 10, but it should work in a similar way on linux (after adapting the paths):

```
library(processx)

while (TRUE) {
  myProcess <- process$new("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe", "https://stackoverflow.com/")
  # myProcess$is_alive()
  # myProcess$get_pid()
  Sys.sleep(10)
  try(myProcess$kill(), silent = TRUE)
}
```

---

Here is another approach hosting a shiny app which opens a new window every 10s (and closes the previous session):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  p("My dummy app")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    Sys.sleep(10)
    runjs("window.close();")
    browseURL("http://127.0.0.1:3838/")
  })
}

myDummyApp <- shinyApp(ui, server)

runApp(appDir = myDummyApp,
        port = 3838,
        launch.browser = TRUE,
        host = "127.0.0.1")
```

Comment: Interesting, how many solutions this problem have? Can we make it with pure c/c++ and embed a code chunk to R-script?

Comment: That's possible for sure :D

Comment: @ismirsehrregal I found an interesting solution in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188581/using-batch-script-to-open-and-close-chrome-however-timeout-only-starts-if-i-clo
Hm, can we embed a batch script in R project. Or it is better to make a batch file and call from R project?

Answer (score 1):

Also, we can to make a solution with only basic things ;)

```
a <- "TRUE"
while(a == TRUE){
    browseURL("https://stackoverflow.com", 
             browser = "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe")
Sys.sleep(10)
system ("TASKKILL /IM iexplore*")
}
```